# Rearrange pandas groupBy output such that the second groupBy label is across the top as headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

### Overview

Here's how I want to display the DataFrame:

```
              Male  Female
Sport_Played              
Basketball       1       2
Hockey           2       1
Soccer           2       1
Volleyball       2       1
```

Here how it's currently being arranged:

```
Sport_Played  Male_or_Female
Basketball    Female            2
              Male              1
Hockey        Female            1
              Male              2
Soccer        Female            1
              Male              2
Volleyball    Female            1
              Male              2
```

Is there a better way to do this then what I did below?

### My Code

```
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(list([['Male', 'Soccer', '18'], ['Male', 'Soccer', '18'], ['Male', 'Hockey', '18'],
                        ['Male', 'Hockey', '18'], ['Female', 'Basketball', '18'], ['Male', 'Volleyball', '18'],
                        ['Male', 'Volleyball', '18'], ['Female', 'Basketball', '18'], ['Female', 'Soccer', '18'],
                        ['Female', 'Hockey', '18'], ['Female', 'Volleyball', '18'], ['Male', 'Basketball', '18']]),
                  columns=['Male_or_Female', 'Sport_Played', 'Age'])

# This is how my output is originally summarized
groupOG= df.groupby(by=['Sport_Played', 'Male_or_Female'])['Sport_Played'].count()

# This is my workaround
group1 = df[df['Male_or_Female'] == 'Male'].groupby(by='Sport_Played')['Sport_Played'].count()
group2 = df[df['Male_or_Female'] == 'Female'].groupby(by='Sport_Played')['Sport_Played'].count()
groupWorkaround= pd.DataFrame({'Male': group1, 'Female': group2})

print(groupOG, groupWorkaround)
```

Comment: DataFrame.stack()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) here.

```
pd.crosstab(df['Sport_Played'], df['Male_or_Female'])

Male_or_Female  Female  Male
Sport_Played
Basketball           2     1
Hockey               1     2
Soccer               1     2
Volleyball           1     2
```

Or

Using [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df.pivot_table(index='Sport_Played', columns = 'Male_or_Female',aggfunc='size')

Male_or_Female  Female  Male
Sport_Played
Basketball           2     1
Hockey               1     2
Soccer               1     2
Volleyball           1     2
```

Or

[`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df.groupby(['Sport_Played','Male_or_Female']).size().unstack()

# Same output as above
```